# Determine number of faces in ASCII STL file

Tags: javascript, 3d

I am parsing an ASCII STL file in JavaScript.  It is in the following format:

```
facet normal ni nj nk
outer loop
    vertex v1x v1y v1z
    vertex v2x v2y v2z
    vertex v3x v3y v3z
endloop
endfacet
```

Based on this information, how can I tell how many faces this 3D object has?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ASCII STL, each face is a triangle, specified between the 'facet' and 'endfacet'. We can just count the number of occurrences of these key-words, to get a count of the faces.

```
var strSTL = "** the STL ASCII string **";
var face_count = strSTL.match(/endfacet/g).length;

alert("The object has " + face_count + " faces.");
```

- I prefer 'endfacet' as the key-word to match, as matching for 'facet' will also match 'endfacet' and complicate things. Also there might other places where 'endloop' might be used.

Hope this does what you want. Let me know if you encounter any issues.